# Print all the nodes in a binary tree which do not have sibling?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

A sibling is a node that has same parent. In a Binary Tree, there can be at most one sibling. Root should not be printed as root cannot have a sibling.

I have written code for this which works fine in all the Testcases which I have used so far but when I tried to submit it in online judge it got wrong for most of the cases. I am not able to figure out what could be the bug although I have tried my best to figure out what it is. Also I can not dry run for that particular Testcases as I do not have access to them.

```
public static void printNodesWithoutSibling(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {

        if(root==null)
        return;


        printNodesWithoutSibling(root.left); 
        printNodesWithoutSibling(root.right);

        if(root.right==null && root.left!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(root.left.data+" ");
            return;
        }



        else if(root.left==null && root.right!=null)
        {

            System.out.print(root.right.data+" ");
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good question for your professor or TA

Comment: Is there at least one sample expected output?  The code always adds a blank space.  Is that acceptable, even for the last node?

Comment: yes 4 of the given testcases ran fine but others 5 couldn't

Comment: It might be depending on the expected traversal. What your code does for each node is printing the "nodes without siblings" in the left sub-tree, then those in the right sub-tree, then eventually printing one of the children of the current node if it has no sibling. Perhaps the expected result has "nodes without siblings" printed as soon as they're met in the traversal. Have you tried putting the if/else _before_ the two recursive invocations?

Comment: @Onheiron yes I have already tried it along with this I have also tried going in right direction first then for left but I got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not take into account the case for a left child without a right sibling.

The required knowledge for determining if a node has a sibling is in its parent.

The following code snippet prints, in preorder, the nodes that do not have a sibling. You could easily modify it is you require it in inorder or postorder. The code is written in c++, but I think that you will not have any problem for refactoring in java

```
void print_nodes_without_sibling(Node * root, bool no_sibling = false)
{
  if (root == nullptr)
    return;

  if (no_sibling)
    cout << root->key << endl;

  print_nodes_without_sibling(root->left,
                              root->left != nullptr and root->right != nullptr);
  print_nodes_without_sibling(root->right,
                              root->left != nullptr and root->right != nullptr);
}
```